# How to convert a list into multiple columns using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Example:

```
l = ['3.4', '3.2', '2.3', '4.3', '2.3']
```

Is there a way to convert the list above into separate columns?

For example, I am can do this:

```
Header
3.4
3.2
2.3
4.3
2.3
```

with the following code:

```
df = pdf.DataFrame(l)
```

However, I would like to achieve the following:

3.4 | 3.2 | 2.3 | 4.3 | 2.3 -> separate columns, rather than rows.

Thank you!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([l])`

Comment: Alternatively, `df.transpose()`

Comment: Or an alias for `transpose`: `df.T`

Comment: The end result, I am looking to get a data frame on separate columns so that I can later export in .csv. I have a larger code that builds multiple lists, and for some reason, transpose doesn't work.

Comment: Can you describe "transpose does not work"? What Output do you see?

Comment: df.T worked. However, here is my next problem. I have a for loop that basically scrapes data off a website. It scrapes 5 values, and loops to the next website for another 5 values. I want the set of the 5 values be places on their own row. So row 1 will have the first 5 values (5 columns), while row 2 will have the next 5 values (5 columns) below the first one. When I do transpose in my code, it basically puts everything on one row in multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

I usually using `Series`

```
df = pd.Series(l).to_frame('Header').T
```

Comment: I think OP wants `pd.Series(l).to_frame('Header').T`.

Comment: Right, so this shows it in rows. I need it in columns, for example:

    Header 1 - 3.4
    Header 2 - 3.2
    Header 3 - 2.3
    Header 4 - 4.3
    Header 5 - 2.3

Comment: @WeNYoBen, always there to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```py
l = ['3.4', '3.2', '2.3', '4.3', '2.3']

for i in range(len(l)):
    if i == list(range(len(l)))[-1]:
        print("└───", end="")
    else:
        print("├───", end="")
    print(l[i])
```

Comment: I may have been not 100% clear.

I am looking for columns. So 5 headers and 1 row.

Comment: Don't you want this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet

```
l = ['3.4', '3.2', '2.3', '4.3', '2.3']
l = np.array(l)
df = pd.DataFrame(l.reshape(-1,len(l)))
df =
    0   1   2   3   4
0   3.4 3.2 2.3 4.3 2.3
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use in similar code, but use list of lists:

```
df = pdf.DataFrame([l])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either `transpose` the dataframe after initialization

```
df.transpose()
```

OR

you can change the list to begin with to change its shape from (4, 1) to (1, 4)

```
l2 = [l]
pd.DataFrame(l2)
```

OR

Create a new dictionary to feed into pandas (dictionaries are the typical way to create a dataframe)

```
colNames = ['a','b','c','d'] 
pd.DataFrame(dict(list(zip(l, colNames))))
```

Cheers!